# How to create new rows in R data frame based on values in cells?

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame:

```
id name shoes
1  Pete "nike; adidas; puma"
2  Anna nike
```

base on this data frame I would like to create the followin data.frame

```
id name shoes
1 Pete  nike
1 Pete  adidas
1 Pete  puma
2 Ana   nike
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your initial data.frame by using `dput()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **tidyverse**'s `separate_rows` function is perfect for this. By default, it separates a string whenever it encounters any non-alphanumeric characters, which includes `;`  in your example.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(name = c('Pete', 'Anna'), shoes = c('nike; adidas; puma', 'nike'))

df_long <- df %>% 
  separate_rows(shoes)

  name  shoes 
  <chr> <chr> 
1 Pete  nike  
2 Pete  adidas
3 Pete  puma  
4 Anna  nike
```

Comment: It should be **tidyr**'s `separate_rows()`. Saying `tidyverse` is not precise.

Comment: Fair point. Notably, the tidyverse as a whole imports magrittr's `%>%` operator (through dplyr, I believe). While I know these are separate packages with different functions, I tend to just import the entire tidyverse suite, since most common workflows will use multiple components from it anyway.

Comment: Nice discussion. `tidyr` also imports magrittr's `%>%` operator, so even if you `library(tidyr)` solely, your code can still work. In my experience on SO, I will say that I'm using a `tidyverse` solution when I need to library more than one packages that are included in `tidyverse` to finish a job.

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `unnest` after `strsplit`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(shoes = strsplit(shoes, "; ")) %>% 
  unnest(shoes)
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     id name  shoes
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 Pete  nike
2     1 Pete  adidas
3     1 Pete  puma
4     2 Anna  nike
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:2, name = c("Pete", "Anna"), shoes = c("nike; adidas; puma",
"nike")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```